# Fastest / easiest way to find rotor wiring without physical inspection on Enigma Machine emulator

Tags: classical-cipher, enigma

We have an Enigma machine emulator we are trying to replicate. Machine has 3 rotor positions and 6 rotors that can be selected. The input goes through 3 rotors then is reflected back to start as is typical.

How can we find the rotor wiring? We are thinking that imputing the same input 26 times while holding the second and third rotors in fixed position is something to do with it (so we get a full rotation of the first rotor). However after this point we are getting a bit stuck. We have tried to simplify this into a 4 letter alphabet to simplify the whole procedure as a test but still are unable to find the wire position.

Unfortunately it's all in software or we could simply remove the rotors and get them with a multi-meter. Is there a better way to find the wiring?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to increase the space between sentences using a double space, but markdown will just convert it to a single space again. This is good because we like to have a consistent look to the Q/A site. Welcome to crypto, upvoted question, hopefully somebody has the answer.